# Include 0 in count(*) function of SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, count, decode

I am using this command to get the status:

```
SELECT  DECODE(processed,1,'Complete', 'Incomplete') Last_Day_Report_Status,       
        COUNT(*) 
FROM Table_demo 
WHERE run_datetime >= trunc(sysdate)-1
  AND run_datetime < trunc(sysdate)
GROUP BY DECODE(processed,1,'Complete','Incomplete');
```

It should give output as follows:

Complete: 120

Incomplete: 0

but it is giving only:
Complete: 120

Answer (score 5):

```
WITH parameter as (
     SELECT 'Complete' as status FROM DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 'Incomplete' as status FROM DUAL
)
SELECT  parameter.status as  Last_Day_Report_Status,       
        COUNT(status) 
FROM parameter 
LEFT JOIN Table_demo 
  ON parameter.status = DECODE(status ,1,'Complete', 'Incomplete')
WHERE run_datetime >= trunc(sysdate)-1
  AND run_datetime < trunc(sysdate)
GROUP BY parameter.status;
```

Answer (score 0):

The advantage of this solution *should be* speed. It summarises Table_demo into a single row, which saves the need for a computed join for each row of Table_demo used.

```
SELECT
  Last_Day_Report_Status, 
  DECODE(Last_Day_Report_Status, 'Complete',  NVL(Completed,0), NVL(Total-Completed,0)) counts
FROM 
   ( SELECT 'Complete' Last_Day_Report_Status FROM DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 'Incomplete' Last_Day_Report_Status FROM DUAL
   )
     OUTER APPLY
  ( SELECT  COUNT(DECODE(processed,1,'Complete')) Completed, COUNT(1) Total
    FROM Table_demo 
    WHERE run_datetime >= TRUNC(SYSDATE)-1
      AND run_datetime < TRUNC(SYSDATE)
  );
```

The big problem with this is the optimiser refuses to process counts sub-query first or do as hash-join even when hinted to death, causing the summation to be run twice, comments welcome. The most explicit optimisation of the query I have (despite the ugly fake join of 1=1), which unfortunately still does nested-loops from the union to the summation, is:

```
SELECT /*+ ordered  */
  Last_Day_Report_Status, 
  DECODE(Last_Day_Report_Status, 'Complete', NVL(Completed,0), NVL(Total-Completed,0)) counts
FROM 
  ( SELECT COUNT(DECODE(processed,1,'Complete')) Completed, COUNT(1) Total
    FROM Table_demo 
    WHERE run_datetime >= TRUNC(SYSDATE)-1
      AND run_datetime < TRUNC(SYSDATE)
  )
   RIGHT OUTER JOIN
 ( SELECT 'Complete' Last_Day_Report_Status FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Incomplete' Last_Day_Report_Status FROM DUAL
 ) ON 1=1;
```

The optimiser felt unable to use the `ORDERED` hint which requests the sub-queries are executed in the order they are written.

Given the optimisation path and assuming Table_demo could be large, the summation can be materialized (pre-canned). The materializing process has a start-up costs, so may be expensive in a loop which executes 100s or 1000s of times a second. Despite the counts materialized query being accessed twice (once for each row of the union) it still requires the undocumented `/*+ MATERIALIZE */` hint to stop it being `INLINE`ed, the standard `ROWNUM` in the `SELECT` to force this will not work as it knows there is only going to be one row. This gives a good optimisation:

```
WITH counts AS
  ( SELECT /*+ MATERIALIZE */ COUNT(DECODE(processed,1,'Complete')) Completed, COUNT(1) Total
    FROM Table_demo 
    WHERE run_datetime >= TRUNC(SYSDATE)-1
      AND run_datetime < TRUNC(SYSDATE)
  )
SELECT
  Last_Day_Report_Status, 
  DECODE(Last_Day_Report_Status, 'Complete',  NVL(Completed,0), NVL(Total-Completed,0)) counts
FROM 
   ( SELECT 'Complete' Last_Day_Report_Status FROM DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 'Incomplete' Last_Day_Report_Status FROM DUAL
   )
     OUTER APPLY
  counts;
```

The optimiser version I'm using is Oracle 12.1.0.1 SE. I took the explain plans at face value without checking against an execution trace.